# Properly align ribbon

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I need to properly align this ribbon whit mine logo, and need to remove white space between `.nav-bar` and `<div class="container">`

This is mine [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/g3PPd6LG0G) example. You can see that mine ribbon hase taken a loot of space inside the `.nav-bar`, so how can I position it properly and overflow it to the `<div class="container">`.

I need to make it look's like this [image: properly align ribbon].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly... but if you just want to reduce the height of `.navbar` so that it isn't influenced by any other element on the page, you can simply declare:

```
.navbar {max-height:40px;}
```

Comment: I will try do that as soon as posible, not at mine laptop atm.

Comment: I am trying to fit the ribbon inside div, so it will look like on the picture, hope this help you understand the problem

Comment: '.navbar {max-height:40px}' did it. Can you suggest me how can I position it to be before mine logo?